# R: Save all data.frames in workspace to separate .RData files

Tags: r, save, workspace

I have several `data.frames` in an environment which I would like to save into separate .RData files. Is there a function which is able to save to whole workspace?

I usually just do this with the following function:

```
save(x, file = "xy.RData")
```

but is there a way I could save all the data.frames separately at once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating a bunch of different files isn't how `save()` is vectorized. Probably better to use a loop here. First, get a vector of all of your data.frame names.

```
dfs<-Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)) , ls())
```

Now write each to a file.

```
for(d in dfs) {
    save(list=d, file=paste0(d, ".RData"))
}
```

Or if you just wanted them all in one file

```
save(list=dfs, file="alldfs.RData")
```

Comment: Isn't `saveRDS` more convenient for storing individual data frames?

Answer (score 3):

To save your workspace you just need to do:

```
save.image("willcontainworkspace.RData")
```

This creates a single file that contains the entire workspace which may or may not be what you want but your question wasn't completely clear to me.

Comment: The OP had a list of data frame's in an environment, and wanted a separate Rdata file for each of them. This does not address that problem.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yeah but they also said "Is there a function which is able to save to whole workspace?".  I'm not saying that mine is exactly what they want but it does answer one of their questions.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @MrFlick's approach, you can do something like this:

```
invisible({
  sapply(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), function(x) {
    obj <- get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    if (class(obj) == "data.frame") {
      save(obj, file = paste0(x, ".RData"))
    }
  })
})
```