# Importing Files using List.Files()

Tags: r

I am trying to import multiple files into R at the same time and name them accordingly (e.g. when I import them into R, I want them named like file_1, file_2, file_3 etc.) - I think I am getting close to figuring this out!

First, I found out the working directory:

```
> getwd()

[1] "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents"

my_dir = getwd()
```

Next, I made a list of all the files I wanted:

```
files = list.files(
    path = wd,
    full.names = TRUE,
    pattern = "*.RDS"
)

[1] "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/basketball_r.RDS"     "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/final.RDS"           
 [3] "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/final_basketball.RDS" "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/extra.RDS"
```

After that, I made a list of file names to assign each of these files to:

```
n = length(files)

names <- list()
for (i in 1:n)

{
 name_i = paste0("file_", i)
names[[i]] <- name_i
}
```

Finally, I tried to create a loop to import and name these files:

```
n = length(files)

for (i in 1:n)

{

names[[i]] = readRDS(files[[i]])

}

for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  assign(paste0("file_", i), as.data.frame(names[[i]]))
}
```

- Have I done this correctly? I would be interested in receiving comments about the code I have written.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste0` is vectorised so you can avoid the `for` loop there. I would do it in the following way.

```
#get the path of RDS files
files <- list.files(path = wd,full.names = TRUE,pattern = "*.RDS")
#Read all the files in a list
data <- lapply(files, readRDS)
#Name them like file_1, file_2 etc. 
names(data) <- paste0("file_", seq_along(data))
```

`data` is a list of dataframes that you need. Usually, it is advised to keep data in a list but for some reason you need them as separate objects in global environment you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

This would create `file_1`, `file_2` as objects in global environment.